# adb - how to capture screen in jpeg format?

Tags: adb, screen-capture

How can I capture the screen in .jpg/.jpeg format using 'screencap'?

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screencap.jpg
```

This does not work. I thought changing the extension would help. But it always captures .png. File size in that case is larger than I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`screencap` does not support JPEG as output format, see [screencap source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.3/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp).

You need to do the conversion yourself after you pull the file from the device.
This can be done with [`imagemagick convert` command](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php), for example:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screencap.png
adb pull /sdcard/screencap.png screencap.png
convert screencap.png screencap.jpg
```

If the file size is still too big, you can resize it:

```
convert screencap.png -resize 50% screencap.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

```
adb shell screencap -j /sdcard/screen.jpg
```

Comment: screencap: invalid option -- j